# The code runs on one pc but not on the other with the same version of python : python config problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, configuration, config

We work at 2 on a project in which we implement TCP mechanisms over UDP connexion. But it seems I have a python config problem. Both of us use Python 3. But the code does work for the other person and not for me.

[Here is what I obtain when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWSvr.png)

And here are my codes :

-server.py

```
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT_A = 7007
PORT_B = 6006

SYN_ACK = b"SYN_ACK6006"
END = b"END"
MAXLINE = 1024
buffer_fichier = bytearray()
buffer_ack = bytearray()
nb_segment = 0
timeout = 0.2

#socket creation
try:
    socket_connect = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error:
    print("socket creation failed")
    exit()

try:
    socket_transfer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error:
    print("socket creation failed")
    exit()

socket_transfer.setblocking(0)

#socket bind
try:
    socket_connect.bind((IP, PORT_A))
except socket.error:
    print("socket bind failed")
    exit()


print("Server waiting for a client")

#tree handshake connection
data, addr = socket_connect.recvfrom(1024)
print("Client: %s" % data)

socket_connect.sendto(SYN_ACK, addr)
print("ME: SYN_ACK")

data, addr = socket_connect.recvfrom(1024)
print("Client: %s" % data)


#open file and put it in a buffer
my_file = open("image.jpg", "rb")
bytes = my_file.read()
my_file.close()
for elem in bytes:
    buffer_fichier.append(elem)
size = len(buffer_fichier)

#file sending
for i in range(0,size,MAXLINE):
    buffer_segment = bytearray()
    buffer_segment.append(nb_segment)
    for j in range(i, i + MAXLINE):
        if j < size:
            buffer_segment.append(buffer_fichier[j])
        else:
            break
    socket_transfer.sendto(buffer_segment, (IP, PORT_B))
    nb_segment += 1
    ready = select.select([socket_transfer], [], [], timeout)
    if ready[0]:
        data, addr = socket_transfer.recvfrom(1)
    else:
        print("pas de ack recu, probleme")
    buffer_ack.append(data)

socket_transfer.sendto(END, (IP, PORT_B))
print("File of %d bytes received" %  os.path.getsize("image.jpg"))
print("nb of ack received %d" % len(buffer_ack))
```

-client.py

```
IP = "127.0.0.1"
PORT_A = 7007

SYN = str.encode("SYN")
ACK = str.encode("ACK")

buffer_ack = bytearray()

#function to slip text and integer in a string
def text_num_split(item):
    for index, letter in enumerate(item, 0):
        if letter.isdigit():
            return [item[:index],item[index:]]

#socket creation
try:
    socket_connect = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error:
    print("socket creation failed")
    exit()

try:
    socket_transfer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
except socket.error:
    print("socket creation failed")
    exit()

#tree handshake connexion
socket_connect.sendto(SYN, (IP, PORT_A))
print("Me: SYN")

data, addr = socket_connect.recvfrom(1024)
msg = text_num_split(data)
PORT_B= int(msg[1])
print("Server: %s" % data)

try:
    socket_transfer.bind((IP, PORT_B)) #on bind  la socket pour qu'elle ecoute
except socket.error:                   #sur le port ou le serveur envoie le fichier
    print("socket bind failed")
    exit()

socket_connect.sendto(ACK, addr)
print("Me: ACK")


#Receive file
my_file = open('my_file', 'w+b')
while True:

    data, addr = socket_transfer.recvfrom(1025)
    if(data == "END"):
        break
    else:
        data = bytearray(data)
        buffer_ack.append(data[0])
        ack = str(data[0])
        socket_transfer.sendto(ack, addr)
        data.pop(0)
        my_file.write(data)

my_file.close()
print("File of %d bytes sent" %  os.path.getsize('my_file'))
print("nb of ack sent %d" % len(buffer_ack))
```

Does anyone see where the problem could be coming from ?

Thanks and have a nice day

Charlotte

Comment: socket.recfrom doesnt return a string but a byte i think enumerate might turn that into ints which dont have .isnumber() which would be the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is your `text_num_split` which assumes you pass it a `string`, you however pass a `bytestring`.
A `bytestring` will be cast to `ints` by `enumerate`.

To fix this add this line to your `text_num_split`

```
item = item.decode("utf-8")
```